# Scheduled system backup

Tags: linux, openvpn, raspbian

I have a Raspberry pi set up running Raspbian and the box is basically dedicated to running OpenVPN server (using pivpn.io). I'd like to set up a cron script to periodically back up the OpenVPN configuration so I can easily copy the setup over to a new memory card should the current one ever die.

I tried backing up bunch of stuff and ending up with a GB worth of backup but even then when restoring to another card I'd have to re-configure the OpenVPN, generate new client ovpn files etc. I'd like to be able to restore what's needed so all my current client keep working towards the new card. I'd also like to copy only what's needed for OpenVPN, I don't really care about anything else. The new card would be a new Raspbian image and hopefully just copy over OpenVPN and voilá.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you only need to copy the contents of /etc/openvpn/ (assuming a similar setup as I have).

Comment: Tried, wasn't enough. None of the certificates were listed as valid after restore.